# POST data is not submitted a situation where I have two alternating forms chosen with show() and hide()

Tags: php, jquery, html, onclick, show

I have 2 forms in a program whereby the second form when showed and then filled up but the keyed-in information never get captured by the POST variables.
Upon click Submit on 2nd form it always go back to 1st form without executing the process A & B in the 2nd form (Sign Up form).
What I need is to execute the process A & B and display a successful message then return to 1st form.

Kindly suggest why it behaves this way and should I change.

## Code:

```
<body>
<div class="container">    
    <div id="loginbox">       
        <form id="loginform" action=""  role="form" method="post">
            <label>Sign in Screen<br></label>
            <label>User id</label>
            <input type="text" name="userid" required>
            <button id="btn-login" type="submit" class="button">Login</button>
            <div class="form-group">
                    <a href="#" onClick="$('#loginbox').hide(); $('#signupbox').show()">
                        Sign up here
                    </a>
            </div>    
        </form>     
    </div>

    <div id="signupbox" style="display:none;" >
        <form id="signupform" action="" role="form" method="post">  
            <label>Sign Up Screen<br></label>
            <?php
                if (isset($POST['name'])) {
                    echo "catch after post data<br>";   
                    //process A here........
                    //process B here........                                    
                }
            ?>
            <label>Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="name" required>
            <button id="btn-signup" type="submit" class="button">Submit</button>
            <div class="form-group">
                    <a href="#" onClick="$('#loginbox').show(); $('#signupbox').hide()">
                        Sign in here
                    </a>
            </div>                              
        </form>    
     </div>     
</div>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> if (isset($POST['name'])) {

should be

```
if (isset($_POST['name'])) {
```

Note: Again you are echoing it inside the hidden div. So to view the echo you have to go to the sign up form.

Comment: My oversight of the variable name. Change it and it works now. Thanks for pointing it out.

Another challange now is once user clicks the submit button in form 2, program jumps back to form 1. While i want to make it stay in form 2 to display succesful process message. I assume it should stay in form 2 until user himself clicks the link to form 1. Any insight as to why will be highly appreciated.

Comment: try adding `<?php
if(isset($_POST['name'])){
 echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\" > $('#loginbox').hide(); $('#signupbox').show(); </script>";
}
?>` at the bottom of your page. Please upvote or accept if it worked for you